# How to select a range of the second row to the last row

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to figure out how to select a range from the second row to the last row, but more specifically between a range of columns. For instance I want to select Range(`A2:L2`) to the last row of data in the spreadsheet.

I have tried,

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A2:L2" & Lastrow).Select
```

But this selects from `A2:L2` all the way down to the bottom of the spreadsheet. I have checked to see if `Lastrow` was incorrect but I printed it to a cell and the correct count of rows displayed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A2:L" & Lastrow).Select
```

Let's pretend that the value of `Lastrow` is 50. When you use the following:

```
Range("A2:L2" & Lastrow).Select
```

Then it is selecting a range from A2 to L250.

Comment: Why is `Range("A2:L2" & Lastrow).Select` selecting from A2 to L250 if Lastrow is 50? I would appreciate an explanation on what math Excel is doing here.

Comment: @TylerH Because we start with "L2" and when we & 50 to it, it's like saying "L2" & "50" which equals "L250"

Comment: @RobertSF Ah, it's concatenating the values, thanks.

Comment: This worked for me except I had to use xlDown instead of xlUp

Answer (score 4):

```
Sub SelectAllCellsInSheet(SheetName As String)
    lastCol = Sheets(SheetName).Range("a1").End(xlToRight).Column
    Lastrow = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Sheets(SheetName).Range("A2", Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Lastrow, lastCol)).Select
End Sub
```

**To use with ActiveSheet:**

```
Call SelectAllCellsInSheet(ActiveSheet.Name)
```