# Copying columns across worksheets to specific row start point

Tags: vba, excel

**Aim**

Copy column from one worksheet to another.

**Issue & Example**

I want to copy a column from S1 to S2 but I want the pasting to start on the second row. I can make it copy to the first cell/row and down but not the second. The code example works for the first four lines, however when I change B1 to B2 it fails to I've also tried adding a Range but to no avail.

**Code:**

```
Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("BatchData")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Portal_Aligned")
    s1.Range("A:A" & LastRow).Copy s2.Range("B1")
    s1.Range("A:A" & LastRow).Copy s2.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
```

**Ref:**

[How to select a range of the second row to the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327037/how-to-select-range-of-second-row-to-last-row-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By additing the row number to `"A1:A" & lastRow` when you copy and by incrementing the `LastRow` by one you ensure that the ranges are of the same size.

```
Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Worksheets("BatchData")
    Set s2 = Worksheets("Portal_Aligned")
    s1.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Copy s2.Range("B1")
    s1.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Copy s2.Range("B2:B" & (LastRow+1))
```

Comment: Hi @Genie If I put A1 this does not work. When I change it to A:A it copies. However regardless of this the s2.Range("B2:... still puts it into the first row. I tried changing this to B5 but it still copied to the first row.

Comment: Check updated code. I did not realise earlier that you did not set your sheets correctly.